# MySQL query: return rows where field is made of characters from the given php string

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a mysql query which will return me all the rows,
where a particular field is made up of characters from a given string.

e.g. I 've this string: `$input = 'abcdef';`
now, I am looking for mysql to result all those rows, where e.g. `'name'` consists of letters from `$input`.

I hope I have expressed myself clearly.. :)

EDIT: Also, for the query you suggest, will it really improve performance, if we are just searching for strings made of letters a-z instead of some patterns, esp. when we are requesting data every 2 seconds.
The thing is that for now, my requirements are to only search among numeric, alpha or alphanumeric formats.. I will be using the exclusive patterns later on.

Regards
Nikhil Gupta

Comment: Are you using a programming language, such as PHP? Where is the $input coming from?

Comment: Yeah... I m using PHP. The input will be coming from user, in the form of GET, or some predefined patterns. I can control `$input` before passing it to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `name` REGEXP '[" . mysql_real_escape_string($input) . "]'";
```

But this query is really weird and will be very slow (depends on how many rows you have).

Comment: so will this work: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE name REGEXP '[a-z]*'` ?? to select all name values which are strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[abcdef]*$'
```

See [MySQL: Regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Comment: `REGEX '^abcdef$'` --- what does this mean?

Comment: I corrected it, it's now '^[abcdef]*$':
^ matches the start of the string,
[abcdef] matches any character from a,b,c,d,e,f,
* matches the previous pattern zero or more times,
$ matches the end of the string.

Comment: Oh, I think you were referring to me having spelled REGEXP incorrectly. Fixed that as well.

Comment: I saw you typoed it, but forgot to mention :-S I pointed to the incorrect regex ;-)